# Remove iframe after printing

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, printing, onbeforeunload

I'm new to HTML and Javascript. I'm trying to write a Javascript function to print the content of an (hidden) iframe in order to print documents (to the user, seemingly) without opening them.

I based the function on the example I found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Printing#Print_an_external_page_without_opening_it

Printing the content works fine but the trouble is removing the iframe from the document after the printing has finished. This is what my code looks like now.

```
function closePrint () {
            var element = document.getElementById("printFrame");
            element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
        }

        function setPrint () {
            this.contentWindow.__container__ = this;
            this.contentWindow.onbeforeunload = setTimeout(closePrint, 100);
            this.contentWindow.onafterprint = setTimeout(closePrint, 100);

            this.contentWindow.focus(); // Required for IE
            this.contentWindow.print();

        }

        function printPage (sURL) {
            var oHiddFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
            oHiddFrame.onload = setPrint;
            oHiddFrame.width = 0;
            oHiddFrame.height = 0;
            oHiddFrame.style.position = "fixed";
            oHiddFrame.style.right = "0";
            oHiddFrame.style.bottom = "0";
            oHiddFrame.id = "printFrame";
            oHiddFrame.src = sURL;
            document.body.appendChild(oHiddFrame);
        }
```

I changed two lines in the example from

```
            this.contentWindow.onbeforeunload = closePrint;
            this.contentWindow.onafterprint = closePrint;
```

to

```
            this.contentWindow.onbeforeunload = setTimeout(closePrint, 100);
            this.contentWindow.onafterprint = setTimeout(closePrint, 100);
```

As it didn't remove the iframes without the timeout.
This works fine in both IE11 and Chrome, but in IE compitability mode (which I think emulates IE7) it gives me an error "Not implemented" when I try to use setTimeout.

So my question is, is there another way to run the closePrint function after a timeout or some other way to remove the iframe from the document when I've printed the content? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to remove lines with `onbeforeunload` and `onafterprint `. And just call `closePrint()` after `this.contentWindow.print();`. This will be working because print function is blocking next js execution.

Comment: @BobSponge I tried your suggestion but it doesn't work. In Chrome it just creates the iframe and then closes it without printing. In IE compitability it prints but doesn't close the iframe. In normal IE11 it actually does work though.

Comment: It works for me, at least in Chrome. Does you trying to print page with same origin (protocol, domain and port)?

Comment: Yes, http, localhost on 8080. Strange stuff. I'll try to experiment some more.

Comment: Ok so it seems that your solution actually works in IE11 with and without compitability mode, the DOM tree just took some seconds to reload/update in the debugger. So I guess I'll just check which browser is used and run code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

after printing, leave the iframe on `document.body`. When you need to add your next `iframe`, first run a check for its presence ~ if its present, remove it then (first two lines).

```
myfunction() {
  const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
  if (iframe) iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
  const i = document.createElement('iframe');
  i.style.display = 'none';
  i.src = this.study.DocumentUrl;
  document.body.appendChild(i);
  document.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.focus();
  document.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.print();
}
```